# Probablity of two card pair

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability that the top two cards in a shuffled deck do not form a pair?
I need some hints on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How many cards are in your deck?
2. After you draw a card, how many cards do you have?
3. How many cards in the remaining deck will make a pair with the first card you drew?
4. Then, how many cards will *not* make a pair.